# Gyro's name in the PR2

Tags: ros, gyro, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you tell me the name of gyro sensor which is embedded in the base of PR2 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46262/gyro%27s-name-in-the-pr2/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MicroStrain Inertial-Link 3DM-GX2

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you for your answer.